# Need some help for new website of an international airline client

Tags: seo, international

Our client wants to create different country sites. They want to structure it in sub folder way. E.g. For India it will be `example.com/in`, for UK it will be `example.com/uk` and so on. There are 87 countries.

Home page, Promotion page & Contacts Page are different for each country & content for these pages will be based on the country you are visiting from.

However rest of the pages e.g. baggage information, payment methods, refunds, FAQs etc. have same content for each and every country.

So my question is for rest of the pages (e.g. baggage information, payment methods, refunds, FAQs etc.) should we create pages for each and every country. This way the links for example will be `example.com/in/baggage-information` , `example.com/uk/baggage-information` , `example.com/us/bagage-information` and all these links will have same content.

Or should we create same page for different countries. This way the link will be `example.com/baggage-information` for all countries.

I fear if we go with first option, we will create duplicate content and it can affect the SEO. Etihad, Emirates and KLM are doing it. Is there any advantages of going first option way?

From a maintenance perspective second option is cost effective and fast. E.g. If we have to update some content on baggage information, we will need to update it at one place however for first option we will have to update the content on 87 pages.

Comment: Will these 'default' pages not be in different languages?

Comment: If the contents are the same I see really no advantages in having multiple URLs... except if you redirect them all to one canonical URL.